# scala: problems with return statement

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm a little puzzled wth this

The following code compiles ok:

```
def save: Action[AnyContent] = Action {
  if (1 == 2) {
    BadRequest(toJson("something went wrong"))
  } else {
    Ok(toJson(Feature.find))
  }
}
```

but if I just add the return statement, I get the following:

```
def save: Action[AnyContent] = Action {
  if (1 == 2) {
    return BadRequest(toJson("something went wrong"))
  } else {
    return Ok(toJson(Feature.find))
  }
}

[error]  found   : play.api.mvc.SimpleResult[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] 
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]
[error]       return BadRequest(toJson("something went wrong"))
```

I thought this two codes would be equivalent...

BTW, Action is a companion object, with an apply method that receives a function of the form: Request[AnyContent] => Result, and that returns an Action[AnyContent]

It seems like with the return statement, the block is returning the result of directly executing BadRequest... and Ok... instead of returning the result of passing the block to the Action object companion...

Am I right?

Note: I'm trying to find a way of getting rid of so many nested map and getOrElse

ps: sorry if the question is a little confuse, I'm confused myself...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These two expressions do very different things indeed!

```
def save: Action[AnyContent] = Action {
  if (1 == 2) {
    BadRequest(toJson("something went wrong"))
  } else {
    Ok(toJson(Feature.find))
  }
}
```

Here, `save` will return the result of `Action(Ok(toJson(Feature.find)))`. Now,

```
def save: Action[AnyContent] = Action {
  if (1 == 2) {
    return BadRequest(toJson("something went wrong"))
  } else {
    return Ok(toJson(Feature.find))
  }
}
```

The situation here is more complicated. When `return Ok(toJson(Feature.find))` is evaluated, *it will return from `save`*! That is, `Ok(toJson(Feature.find))` will *not* be passed to `Action`. Instead, the execution of the method `save` will stop and `Ok(toJson(Feature.find))` will be returned as its result -- except that this is not the type `save` is supposed to return, so it gives a type error.

Remember: `return` returns from the enclosing `def`.

Comment: thanks daniel, I discovered what you said the hard way... is there same way to have an unconditional exit from a function? that is, I'd like the return to be evaluated in the block that is passed to Action...

Comment: @opensas You could always define your function as a `def`, and then pass it as parameter to `Action`.

Comment: **Remember: return returns from the enclosing def** could you please explain what that means?

Comment: @Alex That's too long for a comment. Ask a question.

Answer (score 4):

The method you use is indeed defined in the `Action` companion object, but it is not the one you describe in your question, but rather:

```
def apply (block: ⇒ Result): Action[AnyContent]
```

The argument (`block`) is an expression of type result, that would be evaluated later on demand (by-name evaluation). It is not a function or a closure, just an expression. So you cannot `return` from an expression.

BTW: Using `return` in Scala is a code smell, and should be avoided.

Comment: I had no idea about the difference between functions and expressions, I'll google for it... BTW, perhaps you could help me with this question, that is what started it all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929235/scala-style-how-to-avoid-having-lots-of-nested-map

Comment: @opensas The difference you should check is "function" vs. "call-by-name argument". A call-by-name starts by `=>`.

Comment: @paradigmatic So what you're saying is that the `return` requires a value of the type of containing `method` (method `save` of type `Action[AnyContent]`), rather than the type expected by `Action` (which is type `Result`, or as the compiler reported `SimpleResult`).  Or, in other words, "you cannot `return` from an expression", but you can (and the compiler tries to) return from a method.  Makes sense, thank you.