# Is there some reason to avoid return statements

Tags: scala, conditional-statements, return

Sometimes I see chunks of Scala code, with several nested levels of conditionals and matchings, that would be much clearer using an explicit return to exit from the function.

Is there any benefit in avoiding those explicit return statements?

Comment: here is a related blog post on [return](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A `return` *may be* implemented by throwing an exception, so it *may have* a certain overhead over the standard way of declaring the result of a method. (Thanks for Kim Stebel for pointing out this is not always, maybe not even often, the case.)

Also, a `return` on a closure will return from the method *in which the closure is defined*, and not simply from the closure itself. That makes it both useful for that, and useless for returning a result from closures.

An example of the above:

```
def find[T](seq: Seq[T], predicate: T => Boolean): Option[T] = {
  seq foreach { elem =>
    if (predicate(elem)) return Some(elem) // returns from find
  }
  None
}
```

If you still don't understand, `elem => if (predicate(elem)) return Some(elem)` is the method `apply` of an anonymous object of that implements `Function1` and is passed to `foreach` as parameter. Remove `return` from it, and it won't work.

Comment: Return is not always implemented using exceptions. Just compile a simple while loop with a return statement in it and look at the output with javap -v. In fact, I'd like to see any example where return _is_ implemented that way.

Comment: @KimStebel Interesting, I didn't know Scala optimized that case. As for an example, just look at the code in my answer.

Comment: I sure understadn what you mean when you say that a return on a clousure will return from the method in which it is defined, and not from the clousure itsefl. I've already got burnt with that, as you explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11929485/scala-problems-with-return-statement

Comment: in the example you provide, it makes perfect sense that return would take you out of find, I wish there would be another return statement that would just take you out of the clousure...

Answer (score 2):

One drawback is that the return type can't be inferred. Everything else is a matter of style. What seems unclear or confusing to you might be perfectly "natural" to someone else.

Answer (score 2):

An explicit return breaks the control flow. For example if you have a statement like

```
if(isAuth(user)) {
 return getProfile(user)
}
else {
 return None
}
```

the control structure (if) is not finished, which is the reason why I argue it is more confusing. For me this is analogous to a break statement. Additionally Scalas 'everything is a value' principle reduces the need for using explicit returns which leads to less people using a keyword which is only useful for def statements:

```
// start 
def someString:String = return "somestring"

// def without return 
def someString = "somestring"

// after refactoring
val someString = "somestring"
```

You see that the type annotation has to be added and when changing the def to a val it is  required to remove the return.