# Checking whether an Array[T] is sorted without local tailrec?

Tags: scala

Implement isSorted, which checks whether an Array[A] is sorted according to a given comparison function:

> def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A,A) => Boolean): Boolean

Here is my implementation

```
@tailrec
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  if(as.length==0 || as.length == 1 || as.isEmpty) true
  else if(!ordered(as(0),as(1))) false
  isSorted(as.tail,ordered)
}
```

I got this exception:
 `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.tail`

I don't quite understand, it should return true when `as` is empty.

Comment: use return for boolean like this. if(!ordered(as(0),as(1))) return false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala, the last expression that is evaluated inside a method or block becomes the value for that method or block.

In your case, the last expression that is evaluated inside the method is this:

```
isSorted(as.tail,ordered)
```

So, this is the return value. *Always*.

There is another expression in your method before this expression:

```
if(as.length==0 || as.length == 1 || as.isEmpty) true
else if(!ordered(as(0),as(1))) false
```

But:

- this expression has no side-effects
- the value of this expression is not stored anywhere
- the value of this expression is not returned

Therefore, this expression is essentially a no-op, and your method is really just this:

```
@tailrec
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = 
  isSorted(as.tail,ordered)
```

Your method will simply recurse until the array is empty, and then throw an exception because you are attempting to recurse again with the tail of an empty array.

The simplest possible fix would be to just make this last expression a part of the larger expression, so that your method only consists of a single expression:

```
@tailrec
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  if(as.length==0 || as.length == 1 || as.isEmpty) true
  else if(!ordered(as(0),as(1))) false
  else isSorted(as.tail,ordered)
//↑↑↑↑ This is the only change needed.
}
```

Now, let's go into a small excursion: Scala style!

You have inconsistent whitespace style. Sometimes, you have whitespace around operators, sometimes you don't, and it is not clear when you choose one or the other, and what the meaning of that is. For example, here:

```
if(as.length==0 || as.length == 1 || as.isEmpty) true
//          ↑↑ ↑↑↑↑         ↑↑↑↑ ↑↑↑↑
```

What criteria do you use to decide when to use whitespace or not? What does it mean that you used whitespace around `||` and the second `==` but not the first? What important information is it that you want to tell me, the reader of your code, with that decision?

Personally, I would have written it like this:

```
if(as.length == 0 || as.length == 1 || as.isEmpty) true
//          ↑↑↑↑ ↑↑↑↑         ↑↑↑↑ ↑↑↑↑
```

This is also consistent with the standard Scala Community Style Guidelines.

Likewise, you use whitespace after the comma in parameter lists and no whitespace in argument lists. The standard Scala Community Style Guidelines recommend using whitespace after a comma for readability:

```
else if(!ordered(as(0), as(1))) false
//                     ↑
else isSorted(as.tail, ordered)
//                    ↑
```

The standard Scala Community Style Guidelines also recommend using whitespace after a control-flow keyword such as `if` or `while` to clearly distinguish them from a method call:

```
if (as.length == 0 || as.length == 1 || as.isEmpty) true
//↑
else if (!ordered(as(0), as(1))) false
//     ↑
```

Also, note that checking for zero length and emptiness is redundant, they are the same thing:

```
if (as.length == 1 || as.isEmpty) true
```

And lastly, now that our method only contains a single expression, we don't need the curly braces anymore:

```
@tailrec
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = 
  if (as.length == 1 || as.isEmpty) true
  else if (!ordered(as(0), as(1))) false
  else isSorted(as.tail, ordered)
```

However, there is actually a much better way to solve this: an array is sorted, if every consecutive pair of elements is ordered:

```
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean) = 
  as.sliding(2).forall { case Array(a, b) => ordered(a, b) }
```

The signature of your method is inconvenient. Type inference only flows from one argument list to the next, but not within one argument list, so in your case, the compiler won't know what `A` is in `ordered`, even though it already knows what `A` is in `as`:

```
isSorted(Array(1, 5, 3, 4), (a, b) => a < b)
// error: missing parameter type
// isSorted(Array(1, 5, 3, 4), (a, b) => a < b)
//                              ^
// error: missing parameter type
// isSorted(Array(1, 5, 3, 4), (a, b) => a < b)
//                                 ^
```

You have to explicitly tell the compiler the type:

```
isSorted(Array(1, 5, 3, 4), (a: Int, b: Int) => a < b)
//=> res: Boolean = false
```

For that reason, it is preferable to have the function parameter in a separate parameter list:

```
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A])(ordered: (A, A) => Boolean) = 
  as.sliding(2).forall { case Array(a, b) => ordered(a, b) }
```

Now, type inference works as intended:

```
isSorted(Array(1, 5, 3, 4))((a, b) => a < b)
//=> res: Boolean = false
```

And you can also block syntax for functions with placeholders:

```
isSorted(Array(1, 5, 3, 4)) { _ < _ }
//=> res: Boolean = false
```

Lastly, the signature is actually much more constrained than necessary: nothing actually requires `as` to be an `Array`, it would work just as well with a much more general type such as `Seq`:

```
def isSorted[A](as: Seq[A])(ordered: (A, A) => Boolean) = 
  as.sliding(2).forall { case Seq(a, b) => ordered(a, b) }
```

Now, we could also pass a `List`, for example, instead of only `Array`s. In fact, with a small rewrite of the method, it should be possible to make it work for *all* `Iterable`s.

Answer (score 0):

use return keyword:

```
@tailrec
  def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
    if (as.length == 0 || as.length == 1 || as.isEmpty) return true
    else if (!ordered(as(0), as(1))) return false
    isSorted(as.tail, ordered)
  }
```

or you can do this (recommanded):

```
@tailrec
      def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
        if (as.length == 0 || as.length == 1 || as.isEmpty) return true
        else if (!ordered(as(0), as(1))) return false
        else isSorted(as.tail, ordered)
      }
```

Comment: No. Don't use `return`. Just add `else` before the `isSorted()` recursion.

Comment: yes this can be done!! but what's the problem in using return?

Comment: There are several subtle [reasons to avoid `return`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334471/is-there-some-reason-to-avoid-return-statements). In some situations they can introduce unexpected behavior. Avoiding `return` is just a good habit to follow.